# Bash compare an input array and a text file and update the file

Tags: arrays, string, bash, compare

I have read in a string, split it based on delimiter and store it into an array. I want to iterate through a text file and delete the lines that do not contain the strings I stored in the array. Say my resulting array is  `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge']`

and my text file is:

`foo
grault
bar
xyzzy
baz
quz
quux`

I want to delete the line grault, xyzzy (because they are not in the array) and add corge at the end so my resulting file would be:

`foo
bar
baz
quz
quux
corge`

I am planning to use a for loop to iterate through my array and use grep to add the lines that are missing from the file, but how should I delete the lines that do not exist in the array but exist in the file?

Comment: Where are you reading the string from?  If it's from a file you could just have `grep` read its patterns from that file without splitting it into an array yourself.  Would that work for you?

Comment: From your description, you are simply trying print the array(my assumption) no matter what contains in the file. You should add more example or explain the requirement a bit. Suppose the file doesn't contain any match, what will be the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define the list of approved words:

```
$ words='foo bar baz qux quux corge'
```

Now, let's remove from `file` any word that is not in `words`:

```
$ awk -v s="$words" 'BEGIN{split(s,a,/ /); for (i in a) b[a[i]]} ($0 in b){b[$0]++;print}' file
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

If we want to remove any word not in `words` and also add the end any word in `words` that was not in `file`, then:

```
$ awk -v s="$words" 'BEGIN{split(s,a,/ /); for (i in a) b[a[i]]} ($0 in b){b[$0]++;print} END{for (w in b) if (b[w]==0) print w}' file
foo
bar
baz
quux
corge
qux
```

#### How it works

- `-v s="$words"`

  This defines an awk variable `s` which has the contents of the shell variable `words`.
- `BEGIN{split(s,a,/ /); for (i in a) b[a[i]]}`

  Before we read `file`, this splits up the words in `s` into an array `a` whose values are those words.  Then, we create an associative array `b` with one key for each of the words.
- `($0 in b){b[$0]++;print}`

  As we read through `file`, if the line matches a word in `b`, then increment the count of the number of times that that word has appeared and also print the word.
- `END{for (w in b) if (b[w]==0) print w}`

  After we have finished reading the file, if any word in array `b` was not printed, that is its count `b[w]` is still zero, then print it.

Answer (score 0):

If your original stuff is in a nice file like the second one you can just do

```
(grep -f <good list> <bad list>; echo 'corge')
```

to get the right list otherwise you could try

```
(grep -f <(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}") <bad file>; echo 'corge')
```

which will use process substitution to make your array be like a file that grep could use to search the file for you

This will give you only the lines that are in your word list from the original file, plus `corge` that you had identified.  If you just want the other file to match the word list though you could probably skip all the line matching and just write your array to the file.